# Should I accept an enemy retreat?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-online

When I fight a battle against enemies often when I've killed enough of them they offer a retreat.

What advantages and disadvantages are there to accepting an enemy retreat?

The only advantage I can see at the moment is that I will not lose any more of my army through combat, but will I receive less reward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://forum.clb.heroes-online.com/threads/1812-Allow-Enemy-Retreats):

- You still get the same rewards and XP.
- If you deny retreat, you have a chance to heal your troops, i.e. use spells, run your troops around, slow enemy down and avoid encounter until fully healed.